# How can I access logs of controller-manager and api-server k8s on GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

So for AKS I could use [View Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) controller logs - Azure Kubernetes Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/view-master-logs) and for EKS I could enable logging for these components using [this official tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html).

Is there something similar for GKE?

Answer (score 1):

The way of viewing logs in GKE is using Cloud Operations [1].

Cloud Operations for GKE is designed to monitor GKE clusters. It manages Monitoring and Logging services together and features a Cloud Operations for GKE dashboard that provides a customized interface for GKE clusters:

You can view a cluster's key metrics, such as CPU utilization, memory utilization, and the number of open incidents.

You can view clusters by their infrastructure, workloads, or services.

You can inspect namespaces, nodes, workloads, services, pods, and containers.

For pods and containers, you can view metrics as a function of time and view log entries.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke